# Editor GUI technology choice

Tags: wpf, qt, user-interface

I'm starting making new game engine from scratch (for learning purpose, later mayby for something more).

I stuck on choosing which GUI Technology pick.
I wonder between WPF and Qt, I collected some pros and cons of them:

### **WPF:**

**Advantages:**

1. C# faster development
2. Rich set of ui widgets
3. Visual Studio ecosystem

**Disadvantages:**

1. WPF is dead now ? It's not improving in last years
2. One platform
3. Not so fast ?

### **Qt:**

**Advantages:**

1. Multiplatform
2. It's improves
3. Probably faster then WPF

**Disadvantages:**

1. For my not good visual editor
2. C++, I think development in C++ is slower then in C#

I'm not very familir with gui development, and I don't know what is trend now. 
Which is better choice in you opinion and why ?

Comment: 'WPF is dead now ? It's not improving in last years' - I wont agree with this.

Answer (score 3):

WPF:

- "C# faster development" - wrong. It depends on developer programming
  skills.
- "Rich set of ui widgets" - wrong. Qt has a log of widgets. Including
  third-party.
- "Visual Studio ecosystem" - wrong. Qt has addon for MSVS and
  intergates pretty good.
- "WPF is dead now" - wrong. When technology is "dead" than it means,
  that it is ready for business applications and quite stable.
- "One platform" - wrong. It's is cross-platform.
- "Not so fast" - wrong. It depends on developer programming skills.

Qt:

- "Multiplatform" - true, same as WPF. It is not an advantage.
- "It's improves" - true, same as WPF. It is not an advantage.
- "Probably faster then WPF" - wrong. It depends on developer
  programmming skills.
- "For my not good visual editor" - wrong. Editor is good (for me).
- "C++, I think development in C++ is slower then in C#" - wrong. It
  depends on developer programming skills.

Answer (score 1):

IMO. . Every technology has its own pros and cons.  Don't spend much time on that part.  Instead, try to have good developer team in any of these technology.  It is purely depends on the team and the technology they are familiar with.

If you are new to both then I prefer you to go with WPF as it will provide us great User Interface framework.  Also, you need to learn some part of C# or VB along with WPF.

If you are familiar with C++, then stick with Qt.

Similar question for your reference:  [Choosing between WPF/C# and Qt/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091023/choosing-between-wpf-c-and-qt-c)